# Search All in Smartsheet API

Tags: curl

when using the Search All api, the documentation list a scopes parameter to limit the objects searched - however using curl or bridge to call the api I cannot limit it to just sheetNames per the parameter - has anyone used it with success? THanks

Tried this in bridge calling the API and expected an array of only sheets to come back